# Nginx Lua module for redirecting based on proxy and access headers

Tags: nginx, lua, webserver

In nginx I want to redirect the user based on access and proxy headers. When I put it to the response header, they are shown correctly in the browser. But when using in lua to redirect with an `if` it does not.

For user with access app creates string `isprotectedfalse` and for guests I get `isprotected`

```
        add_header X-User-Access-Flag  $userinfo$arg_limit$upstream_http_x_doc_protection; #this works
        if ($http_x_user_access_flag = "isprotected") { #this doesnt
          return 302 $scheme://$http_host$uri?limit=true;
        }
```

and similar code but in lua:

```
             rewrite_by_lua_block {
                local params = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
                local limit = params["limit"]
                local headers = ngx.resp.get_headers()
                local useraccesss = headers["X-User-Access-Flag"]
                if useraccesss == "isprotected" and limit == nil then
                    local delimiter = (ngx.var.is_args == "" or ngx.var.is_args == nil) and "?" or "&"
                    local new_url = ngx.var.request_uri .. delimiter .. "limit=true" 
                    return ngx.redirect(new_url)
                end
             }
```

why is it not redirecting as expected?

Edit:
From using `header_filter_by_lua_block`

I have managed to access them from `ngx.var['upstream_http_x_user_access_flag']` which is used before the lua block to set X-User-Access-Flag (from proxy_pass). But sadly server errors on redirection try (headers sent). Seems at this point headers are already sent (but I am still able to set a custom header there which does work?! so this is confusing...)

I can not access such `ngx.var` from `rewrite_by_lua_block` as this has not performed `proxy_pass` yet. How could I access this variables `after` `auth` + `proxy_pass` and redirect based on aquired headers?

Comment: I surmise the issue you're facing is due to **the order of Nginx phases**. The `rewrite_by_lua_block` runs before the `proxy_pass`, so the headers from the upstream server are not yet available.

Comment: @mandy8055 I already wrote regarding this point in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on [mandy8055](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19090048/mandy8055)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567066/nginx-lua-module-for-redirecting-based-on-proxy-and-access-headers#comment136775270_77567066), when you consider [Nginx HTTP phases](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases), you do see that a request goes through several stages or "phases," each designed for specific tasks.

1. **Rewrite Phase**: includes `rewrite_by_lua_block`. That is where URL modifications occur.
2. **Access Phase**: access control checks are performed here.
3. **Content Phase**: the `proxy_pass` directive functions in this phase, fetching content from an upstream server.
4. **Header Filter Phase**: includes `header_filter_by_lua_block`. That is where response headers from the upstream server can be manipulated.

In your case, the [`rewrite_by_lua_block`](https://nginx-lua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lua-nginx-module/DIRECTIVES/#rewrite_by_lua_block) is executed during the `Rewrite` Phase, which happens before the `Content` Phase where `proxy_pass` sets the upstream headers.
So, when your Lua script in the `rewrite_by_lua_block` tries to access headers set by `proxy_pass`, they are not available yet because `proxy_pass` has not executed.

Same for [`access_by_lua_block`](https://nginx-lua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lua-nginx-module/DIRECTIVES/#access_by_lua_block), executed in the "`access tail`" phase, which is before the "`content`" phase where `proxy_pass` operates.

> Would it be possible to use `ngx.exec` to route to a `location` which does `proxy_pass` and has passed down headers? `location.capture` does not seem to getting set headers (I have to pass user info headers from the nginx `access` phase).

The suggestion to use `ngx.exec` to route to a location which performs a `proxy_pass` and handles headers can be a good workaround solution, especially if `ngx.location.capture` is not meeting the requirements.

[`ngx.exec`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxexec) performs an internal redirection to a different location in Nginx. Unlike HTTP redirects, this happens *server-side* and is transparent to the client.

You can set variables in Nginx that can then be read in the target location. These variables can carry information from headers processed in the `access` phase.

Set the necessary headers or variables in the `access` phase.

```
location /initial {
    access_by_lua_block {
        -- Set Nginx variables based on headers or other logic
        ngx.var.user_info = ngx.req.get_headers()["User-Info"] or "default"
        -- Additional access phase logic
    }

    # Use ngx.exec to internally redirect to a different location
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.exec("/internal_proxy")
    }
}
```

A request to `/initial` goes through the access phase, where specific logic is applied, and variables are set based on the request headers or other criteria. `ngx.exec("/internal_proxy")` then internally redirects the request to `/internal_proxy`.

Use the variables set in the previous phase for `proxy_pass` and additional logic.

```
location /internal_proxy {
    proxy_set_header User-Info $user_info;  # Pass the user info to the upstream server
    proxy_pass http://upstream_server;
    # Additional proxy settings
}
```

In `/internal_proxy`, the `proxy_pass` directive is used to forward the request to the upstream server, including any headers or variables set in the previous phase.

Comment: from the linked docs it looks like `access` is called before the content phase. I tried it in the code but it does not read the headers neither it reads `set $passValue $upstream_http_...` values. Ends up with no redirection at all

Comment: @Trouble OK, I have rewritten the answer to propose an alternative approach.

Comment: I can not imagine this would be anyhow secure if the redirect happens on client side to `/step2`. I could do it better to call initially in `auth` url from `proxy_pass` to get headers and pass them to the `lua` block. But this seems wrong to do 2 requests to `proxied url` for one client request (one for auth - eg from express.js server to get headers which can be passes and one for the actual request to the proxy_pass). Especially that I *can* set headers correctly on `header_filter_by_lua_block`, but it has no access to `api` for redirect.

Comment: @Trouble True, a Lua subrequest should be safer. I have edited the answer to include that alternative.

Comment: this is better, but as I understand it still does two requests to the protected content per one client request. This halves the performance of system

Comment: @Trouble I have edited the answer to explain why two requests (which is not ideal, but I cannot find a better solution for now).

Comment: when I am doing it the way you described, content is always shown from `proxy_pass` (which is defined after the lua content block). When I remove `proxy_pass` after the lua content block it redirects correctly to parameter. Is it possible to write `proxy_pass` in lua else condition?

Comment: @Trouble OK, I have edited the answer to propose a solution.

Comment: The location.capture is by definition synchronous, but not blocking. In real case it does not complete on time and ends up in the `else` case, throwing out the unprotected value. Is there another api which could be used to wait for this to finish and then to read headers it responds with?

Comment: @Trouble [`cosockets`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#cosockets-not-available-everywhere), maybe? I have edited the answer.

Comment: would it be possible to use ngx.exec to route to a `location` which does proxy_pass and has passed down headers? `location.capture` seems not getting set headers (I have to pass user info headers from the nginx `access` phase)

Comment: @Trouble Good point. I have edited the answer to illustrate how that would work.

Comment: @Trouble To clarify this answer, would it be accurate to keep only the last part, where I describe how to use `ngx.exec` to route to a location which does `proxy_pass` and has passed down headers? Is that what worked for you in the end?

Comment: correct, this worked

Comment: @Trouble OK. I have cleaned up the answer. Let me know if I missed anything.